# Let $R \in \textbf{Ring}$. Show that $A_1 \otimes_R A_2 \in \textbf{Ring}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

We denote $\textbf{Ring}$ the category of conmutative rings with $1$.

Let $R \in \textbf{Ring}$. Consider $\phi_1: R \to A_1$ and $\phi_2: R \to A_2$ ring morphisms.

I have to show three things:

1. Show that the tensor product $A_1 \otimes_R A_2 \in \textbf{Ring}$ (considering $A_1$ and $A_2$ as $R-$modules).
2. Show there are $\lambda_1: A_1 \to A_1 \otimes_R A_2$ and $\lambda_2: A_2 \to A_1 \otimes_R A_2$ ring morphisms.
3. Show that the following square is a Pushout in $\textbf{Ring}$:

[image]

I'm a little bit confused with the writing of the exercise and with the idea of every required proof.

For the first proof, do we need to consider an arbitrary right $R-$module $A_1$ and an arbitrary left $R-$module $A_2$, in order to define the tensor product $A_1 \otimes_R A_2 $, and to show that $A_1 \otimes_R A_2 \in \textbf{Ring}$, right?

For the second proof, to find $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ morphisms in $\textbf{Ring}$, we need that $A_1, A_2 \in \textbf{Ring}$. But, for arbitrary $A_1$ and $A_2$ $R-$modules, why should $A_1, A_2 \in \textbf{Ring}$?

Comment: No, $A_1$ and $A_2$ are rings. If they were just modules there would be no candidate for the multiplication. Personally I think whoever wrote this exercise phrased it poorly; it doesn't make sense to say that something is a ring without describing a candidate for multiplication. You'll need to work out for yourself what the multiplication is supposed to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good exercise, but is confusingly written. Here's a longer version of the same question, along with some hints, which should hopefully clarify the question and help you solve it!

For your first question: $A_1$ and $A_2$ are rings, and $\varphi_1 : R \to A_1$, $\varphi_2 : R \to A_2$ are ring homomorphisms. These maps give $A_1$ and $A_2$ the ~bonus structure~ of left/right $R$-modules, by using the multiplication in $A_1$ and $A_2$ to define

- $r \cdot a_1 = \varphi_1(r) a_1$
- $a_2 \cdot r = a_2 \varphi_2(r)$

Now we can take the tensor product in the category of $R$-modules, and get a new $R$-module $A_1 \otimes_R A_2$.

Then question (1) asks you to show that this object $A_1 \otimes_R A_2$, which we know is an $R$-module, is actually *also* a ring! I'll give you a hint that you should define the multiplication as $(a_1 \otimes a_2) (a_1' \otimes a_2') = a_1 a_1' \otimes a_2 a_2'$, using the multiplication in $A_1$ and $A_2$ in each slot. This also hopefully explains your confusin with question (2). You're right that it's *not* obvious that $A_1 \otimes_R A_2$ is a ring, but in question (1) you showed that it secretly is one!

Now that you've shown this, question (2) makes sense, and asks you to find ring morphisms $\lambda_1 : A_1 \to A_1 \otimes_R A_2$ and $\lambda_2 : A_2 \to A_1 \otimes_R A_2$. Again, I'll give you a hint that the right map to consider is $\lambda_1(a_1) = a_1 \otimes 1_{A_2}$ (and similarly for $\lambda_2$). Do you see how to show these are ring maps?

Then lastly, for question (3) you're meant to show that this square is a pushout in the category of rings. So you want to show that for any ring $S$ with ring maps $\alpha_1 : A_1 \to S$ and $\alpha_2 : A_2 \to S$ so that $\alpha_1 \circ \varphi_1 = \alpha_2 \circ \varphi_2 : R \to S$, there should be a unique ring map $A_1 \otimes_R A_2 \to S$. Again, I'll give you a hint that the correct map to consider is $a_1 \otimes a_2 \mapsto \alpha_1(a_1) \alpha_2(a_2)$, using the multiplication in $S$. Can you show this is well defined and a ring hom?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Nice answer. I'm sure you know the following, but the OP seems like they might not have a lot of experience with tensor products, so I think it's worth noting two things:
1) You've actually only defined the multiplication on simple tensors. One has to define the multiplication on all elements of the tensor product, which are sums of simple tensors obeying certain rules. (Again, I'm sure this nit is clear to experts, and maybe it's self-evident how to extend things, but this detail should be addressed by the OP.)
2) You have to check that this multiplication is well-defined. This is a...

Comment: ...tedious detail to check, but is again important. I think the best tools to use here are probably the universal property of the tensor product and the universal property of the product.

Comment: Do $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ defined as above are a monomorphisms, right? This guarantees the uniqueness of the morphism in the Universal Property of Pushouts, right?

Comment: @BlueTomato -- You can write coequalizers (that is, quotient rings) as a pushout in a way that makes $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = q$ the usual quotient map. So in general the $\lambda_i$s don't have to be monomorphisms. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703377/constructing-coequalizers-via-pushouts-and-initial-objects) for instance.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thank you so much for your help!!! In the last part, to observe that the morphism $\gamma: A_1 \otimes_R A_2 \to S$ is unique, one can observe that, indeed, $\gamma: A_1 \times A_2 \to S$. Thus, is unique due to the U.P. of Tensor Product.