# "Distributive property" and "Ring homomorphism" with $A \otimes_R B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

Let $R, A, B$ commutative rings with unity. Consider ring homomorphisms $\phi_1:R \to A$ and $\phi_2:R \to B$.

Then can build the $R-$module tensor product $A \otimes_R B$. We know $A \otimes_R B$ is an abelian group with the additive operation in $R$.

Let $\phi: A \times B \to A \otimes_R B$ be the canonical $R-$bilinear map.

Define $\cdot_R: (A \otimes_R B)\times (A \otimes_R B) \to A \otimes_R B$ as $\phi(a, b) \cdot_R \phi(a', b') = \phi(aa', bb')$.

I have two questions:

1. Can the additive operation in $A \otimes_R B$ be defined in terms of $\phi$? Behind this question, I want to show that $\cdot_R$ distributes the additive operation in $A \otimes_R B$, but I clearly don't understand how to achieve this.
2. Let $C$ be another commutative ring with unity and $f: A \to C$, $g: B \to C$ two ring homomorphisms. I define $\gamma: A \otimes_R B \to C$ as $\gamma(\phi(a, b)) = f(a)g(b)$. How can I prove that $\gamma$ opens addition? That is

$$\gamma(\phi(a,b) + \phi(a',b')) = \gamma(\phi(a,b)) + \gamma(\phi(a',b'))$$

The root of the problem is that I don't understand how addition is defined in $A \otimes_R B $.

The original problem underlying can be find here:

[Let $R \in \textbf{Ring}$. Show that $A_1 \otimes_R A_2 \in \textbf{Ring}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4779087/let-r-in-textbfring-show-that-a-1-otimes-r-a-2-in-textbfring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use the standard construction of $A\otimes_R B$. I'm going to pretend $A$ and $B$ are both $R$-modules for notational convenience, this can be formalised with the $\phi_{1,2}$. Things like $ra$ for $r\in R$ and $a\in A$ are defined as $\phi_1(r)\cdot a$. The fact all rings involved are commutative is important.

We take the **free Abelian group** on the *set* $A\times B$ - let's call this $F$. The elements of the group $F$ are *linear combinations* of the generators, one for each pair $(a,b)\in A\times B$. Addition in $F$ is purely "formal". In fact, $F$ is more correctly stated as the set of all functions $f:A\times B\to\Bbb Z$ for which $f(a,b)=0$ for all but finitely many pairs $(a,b)$. The addition $f+g$ is defined as the obvious function $(a,b)\mapsto f(a,b)+g(a,b)$. We interpret a function $f$ as a linear combination by considering the ("formal"; this is just notation) sum $\sum_{(a,b)\in A\times B}f(a,b)\cdot(a,b)$ e.g. $(a_1,b_1)+2(a_2,b_2)-3(a_3,b_3)$... but this notation is really just a placeholder for the definition via functions. Then we consider the subgroup $G$ which is generated by elements of form:

- $(ra,b)-(a,rb)$ for $a,b,r$ in $A,B,R$
- $(a,b)+(a',b)-(a+a',b)$ for $a,a'\in A$ and $b\in B$
- $(a,b)+(a,b')-(a,b+b')$ for $a\in A$ and $b,b'\in B$

And finally construct $A\otimes_RB$ as the *Abelian group quotient* $F/G$. Notice that the Abelian group "addition" structure on $A\otimes_RB$ is *automatically given to us*: any quotient group is... well, a group! "Explicitly" the addition works as follows: $$[k_1(a_1,b_1)+k_2(a_2,b_2)+\cdots]+[k'_1(a'_1,b'_1)+\cdots]:=[k_1(a_1,b_1)+\cdots+k'_1(a'_1,b'_1)+\cdots]$$Where $[]$ denotes equivalence classes in the quotient and the $k_\bullet,k'_\bullet$ are any **finite** selection of integers and the pairs $(a_\bullet,b_\bullet),(a'_\bullet,b'_\bullet)$ are any arbitrary finite selection of elements of $A\times B$. Each $[(a,b)]$ is usually written $a\otimes b$ and is called a "pure tensor".

Now to the issue of multiplication. Your definition of $\cdot_R$ is not really a definition at all, there are two issues. Issue number $(1)$: you have to check it is well defined! For $\phi$ is not injective so $\phi(a,b)=\phi(a',b')$ is quite possible for distinct pairs. Issue number $(2)$ is very similar: $\phi$ is not surjective either (in general)! Not all elements of $A\otimes_RB$ are "pure tensors" (the things usually written as $a\otimes b$, i.e. $\phi(a,b)$).

---

About the ring structure on $A\otimes_R B$. I object to your "definition" and also to the definition given in your linked question; not because it's wrong per se but because it is not enough - more work needs to be done. We seek a suitable $m:A\otimes_RB\times A\otimes_RB\to A\otimes_RB$ and this is best done by, for each $x\in A\otimes_RB$, defining $m(x,-):A\otimes_RB\to A\otimes_RB$ since maps out of $A\otimes_RB$ are easy to define. We have to find a suitable "$R$-balanced product" $A\times B\to A\otimes_RB$. Let $\sum_{j=1}^nk_j(a_j,b_j)$ be a finite linear combination representing $x$. We can define a map $h:A\times B\to A\otimes_RB$ by $h(a,b):=[\sum_{j=1}^n k_j(a\cdot a_j,b\cdot b_j)]$. We need to check that this is well-defined and that this is an $R$-balanced product. Assuming $h$ *is* well-defined, the last statement is quite easy to see. The first statement is a bit harder to check; you have to realise that if $x$ is also represented by a different linear combination, then there is a finite sequence of "moves" which takes the first combination to the second; then, you must observe that the multiplication by $(a,b)$ does not affect any of these "moves" in the sense that you stay within the same equivalence class.

Once you've done all that, you have a bona fide *group homomorphism* $m(x,-):A\otimes_RB\to A\otimes_RB$ uniquely induced from $h$. Now of course you need to show $m$ defines a commutative unital and associative operation which distributes over addition. Some of this is automatic; the unital criterion is easy to check and $m(x,y+z)=m(x,y)+m(x,z)$ is automatic from the fact $m(x,-)$ is a group homomorphism. To get the other claims, it is best to first show each $m(-,y)$ is also a group homomorphism (i.e. it comes from an $R$-balanced product) and therefore it suffices to check all further conditions on the pure tensors only, which is easier.

---

<s>A quick internet search suggests that $A\otimes_RB$ is not in general a ring. We can only expect it to be an $R$-*module*</s>; you need to be searching for a multiplication map $m:R\times A\otimes_RB\to A\otimes_RB$ which satisfies some axioms. One does this as follows; for each fixed $r\in R$, we have a homomorphism $F\to F$ which is defined as the linear extension of $(a,b)\mapsto(ra,b)$. This map clearly descends to a homomorphism $m(r,\bullet):A\otimes_RB\to A\otimes_RB$ by the universal property of a quotient group. Now, your task is to check that $m(r,-)+m(r',-)$ and $m(r+r',-)$ are the same homomorphism and that $m(rr',-)$ and $m(r,m(r',-))$ are the same homomorphism. This is best done by using the universal property again (well, in this direction we just use surjectivity of the quotient map $F\twoheadrightarrow F/G=A\otimes_RB$). I guess I should leave this as an exercise, now that you know what you need to show.

As for point $(2)$, you make the same (conceptual) mistake when you say "that is": $\phi$ isn't in general surjective, so checking $\gamma\circ\phi$ respects addition isn't immediately enough... but in a sense it *is* enough. Sorry. The real thing you need to do is check that you have a bilinear "$R$-balanced product" $A\times B\to C$. Then (extremely important but straightforward exercise!) you use the definition of $A\otimes_RB$ as a quotient group to prove there is a genuine group homomorphism $\gamma:A\otimes_RB\to C$ such that $\gamma(a\otimes b)=f(a)g(b)$ on pure tensors.

More abstractly, this property that guarantees existence of $\gamma$ is the real reason we care about the tensor product. It's common to define the tensor product by this property, and then consider the construction as an important but secondary detail.

Comment: With the second part u wrote, I understand that $\gamma$ may be a ring homomorphism: Since $\sigma:A \times B \to C$ defined as $(a, b) \mapsto f(a)g(b)$ is $R–$bilinear ($f$ and $g$ are ring morphisms), by the U.P. of Tensor Product, there is a unique $R–$module morphism $\sigma': A \otimes_R B \to C$ s.t. $\sigma' \circ \phi = \sigma$. It can be verified that $\gamma = \sigma'$. Thus, $\gamma(x+y) = \gamma(x) + \gamma(y)$, for every $x,y \in A \otimes_R B$. The other two conditions of ring morphism are easy to prove. Let me know if I'm wrong, but we can conclude $\gamma$ is ring morphism.

Comment: The question says $R,A,B$ are commutative rings; in that case, the given definition of multiplication does work out to be well-defined and give a ring structure.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, it yields!! Actually the distributive property of the product over the addition and the condition that $\gamma$ respects additions, follows from the U.P. of Tensor Product (as I wrote above).

Comment: @DanielSchepler it cannot be well defined as it is not even defined on every element of the tensor product. But I will admit I made an oversight and did not know it formed a ring

Comment: @BlueTomato I've added some commentary on the ring structure and a sketch of how you can show commutativity, distributivity etc.

Comment: @FShrike Thanks mate! In the part of ring structure, I noted that, since $\phi$ es $R–$bilinear map, and for a fixed $(a, b) \in A\times B$, defining the $R–$bilinear map $\psi_{(a,b)}: A \times B \to A \otimes_R B$ such that $(x, y) \mapsto \phi(ax, ay)$, por every $(x, y) \in A \times B$. Thus, by the U.P.T.P., there is a unique $R-$module morphism $\tilde{\psi}_{(a, b)}: A \otimes_R B \to A \otimes_R B$, s.t. $\tilde{\psi}_{(a, b)} \circ \phi = \psi_{(a, b)}$, and because it is $R-$module morphism, the distributive property yields. In this context, $\phi = h$. This could also work, right?

Comment: @BlueTomato You also need to be able to multiply other elements of the tensor product. So your $\overline{\psi_{(a,b)}}$ is a special case of the construction I suggest; it maps $x\mapsto(a\otimes b)\cdot x$ but we also need a way to multiply things like $(a\otimes b+c\otimes d)\cdot x$. You could just say: well, obviously define this as $(a\otimes b)\cdot x+(c\otimes d)\cdot x$. But that's not good enough since it is possible that $a\otimes b+c\otimes d=a'\otimes b'+c'\otimes d'$ for some different $a',b',c',d'$ so you need to check this is well defined. That's going to lead to my suggestion.