# Show $R_1 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \cdots \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R_n$ is coproduct on Ring Category

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory

Let Ring be the category of commutative rings with unit.

I'm required to show that $R_1 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \cdots \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R_n$ is coproduct on Ring Category. Note that the family needs to be finite.

Def: A coproduct of a family $f_i: R_i \to T$ is defined as the unique morphism $\psi: T \to T'$, given another family $g_i: R_i \to T'$, such that $\psi \circ f_i = g_i$. We are assuming (for the definition) that every $\mu_i$ is an inclusion and that the set of indexes $I$ is arbitrary.

[We already know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4779087/let-r-in-textbfring-show-that-a-1-otimes-r-a-2-in-textbfring/4779103?noredirect=1#comment10157327_4779103) that $R_1 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \cdots \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R_n$ is a Ring. I dont think we need this Pushout property..

By construction of $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$, for every $t \in A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$, there are $a \in A, b \in B$, such that $\phi(a, b) = t$, where $\phi: A \times B \to A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$ is the canonical $R-$bilinear map.

So, I'm letting myself inductively define $\phi: R_1 \times\cdots \times R_n \to R_1 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \cdots \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R_n$ as the canonical $\mathbb{Z}-$module $n-$linear map such that for every $t \in R_1 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \cdots \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R_n$, there is some $(r_1, \cdots, r_n) \in R_1 \times \cdots \times R_n$ such that $\phi(r_1, \cdots, r_n) = t$. Rename $T:=R_1 \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \cdots \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R_n$.

By construction (and inductively) $f_i: R_i \to T$ is defined as $f_i(r) = \phi(1, \cdots, r, \cdots, 1)$, for every $r \in R_i$, meaning that $r \mapsto \phi(1, \cdots, r, \cdots, 1)$, where $r$ is in the $i-$th position of the entry of $\phi$.

Let $g_i: R_i \to T'$ be a finite family of ring morphisms. We want to find a unique $\psi: T \to T'$ such that $\psi \circ f_i = g_i$. We know, by the universal property of Tensor Product, that if we find $\phi': R_1 \times \cdots \times R_n \to T'$ a $\mathbb{Z}-$module $n-$linear map, there is a unique $\mathbb{Z}-$module morphism $\psi: T \to T'$ such that $\psi \circ \phi = \phi'$.

I define $\phi': R_1 \times \cdots \times R_n \to T'$ as $\phi'(r_1, r_2, \cdots, r_n) = g_1(r_1)g_2(r_2) \cdots g_n(r_n)$, for every $(r_1, r_2, \cdots, r_n) \in R_1 \times \cdots \times R_n$. (I'll omitte the proof it is $n$-linear mapping, but for the case of two tensor product modules is defined as mentioned). So there is a unique morphism $\psi: T \to T'$ such that $\psi \circ \phi = \phi'$.

I proposed $\psi$ as the desired morphism such that $\psi \circ f_i = g_i$. So, let $r \in R_i$. Then, $$(\psi \circ f_i)(r) = (\psi \circ \phi)(1, \cdots, r, \cdots, 1) = \phi'(1, \cdots, r, \cdots, 1) = g_1(1)g_2(1) \cdots g_i(r) \cdots g_n(1) = g_i(r)$$

Therefore $\psi: T \to T'$ is coproduct.

I've three questions:

1. Is this proof correct?
2. The hint of the exercise and some Internet searches suggest $R_i$ are all $\mathbb{Z}-$modules. Then, where was supposed to be use this fact? It is clear that $\phi$ and $\phi'$ needs all $R_i$ to be defined as $R-$modules. But why specifically the initial object $\mathbb{Z}$?
3. Does this could hold for an infinite tensor product?

Comment: Your proof seems essentially correct, but you proved existence and no uniqueness. However, the claim you make at the beginning that $\forall t\in R_1\otimes R_2$, there exists $a,b\in R$ such that $\phi(a,b)=t$ is false : this is only true for pure tensors (which are usually written $a\otimes b$ rather than $\phi(a,b)$). Fortunately you don't use this claim in the rest of the proof. For your second question, you use it by invoking the universal property of the tensor product of $\mathbb Z$-modules.

Comment: @vanxoo you’re right, I forgot to prove uniqueness. Thanks for the clarification of the pure tensors. The last detail about the universal property of the tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules I don’t clearly see why this only should work for integers. Could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: It always works. With the same proof, for any ring $k$ you can use the universal property of $\otimes_k$ (classifying $k$-bilinear maps) to  prove that $A\otimes_k B$ is the coproduct of $A$ and $B$ in the category of $k$-algebras.

Comment: @vanxoo Thats right! Thanks mate!